# .NET Encrypt bytearray

Tags: c#, .net, encryption

Is there any way to encrypt a bytearray without using a stream??

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are concerned about disk I/O you can use a MemoryStream.

However, the RSACryptoServiceProvider class will operate on byte arrays.  This class performs asymmetric encryption and decryption using an implementation of the RSA algorithm.

The examples [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.rsacryptoserviceprovider.aspx) show how you can do this with byte arrays

Answer (score 15):

In fact you don't need to use any streams at all to operate with bytes.
The only thing you need is to call TransformFinalBlock() method of ICryptoTransform which can be encryptor or decryptor of any algorithm derived from SymmetricAlgorithm class

```
public class CryptoProvider
{
    private SymmetricAlgorithm _algorithm = new RijndaelManaged();

    public byte[] EncryptData(byte[] data, string password)
    {
        GetKey(password);

        ICryptoTransform encryptor = _algorithm.CreateEncryptor();

        byte[] cryptoData = encryptor.TransformFinalBlock(data, 0, data.Length);

        return cryptoData;
    }

    public byte[] DecryptData(byte[] cryptoData, string password)
    {
        GetKey(password);

        ICryptoTransform decryptor = _algorithm.CreateDecryptor();

        byte[] data = decryptor.TransformFinalBlock(cryptoData, 0, cryptoData.Length);

        return data;
    }

    private void GetKey(string password)
    {
        byte[] salt = new byte[8];

        byte[] passwordBytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(password);

        int length = Math.Min(passwordBytes.Length, salt.Length);

        for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
            salt[i] = passwordBytes[i];

        Rfc2898DeriveBytes key = new Rfc2898DeriveBytes(password, salt);

        _algorithm.Key = key.GetBytes(_algorithm.KeySize / 8);
        _algorithm.IV = key.GetBytes(_algorithm.BlockSize / 8);

    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Well, you *could* write your own encryption algorithms - but it's much easier just to use the built-in streaming API writing to a [`MemoryStream`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.memorystream.aspx) which you then convert to a byte array using [`ToArray`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.memorystream.toarray.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

Using the [Cryptography Application Block](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd139964.aspx) of Microsofts Enterprise Library you can do this, but I agree with the others that you don't really get any benefits from not using a stream.

Answer (score 0):

http://www.obviex.com/samples/Code.aspx?Source=EncryptionCS&Title=Symmetric%20Key%20Encryption&Lang=C%23

Answer (score -1):

Use a block cypher and implement it yourself.

But this is almost certainly pointless since using a MemoryStream on the byte array should work just fine and will use a well tested implementation.

Implementing something yourself when you're talking about crypto is *normally* a bad idea.